Pdo: alter table ıf not exısts
I want to say do nothing if there is a column in the table, otherwise add the column, but I couldn't do it.
I want to do this with PHP and PDO.
This works. But it doesn't check if the column exists in the table.
$sorgu = $baglanti->prepare("ALTER TABLE gecici ADD Email1 varchar(255)");
$sorgu->execute();

This does not work.
$sorgu = $baglanti->prepare("ALTER TABLE gecici ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS Email1 varchar(255)");
$sorgu->execute();

Thanks in advance for your help.

"This does not work" how? Also what is your database engine - mysql, postgres, oracle, etc?

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 8.0.32 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

You could query the database schema in PHP and deduce if the column exists before trying to modify the table

Check the column presence and properties from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. If the column is absent then add it. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

ALTER TABLE IF NOT EXISTS only exists in MariaDB but not in MySQL. So you have to check the column first.

When you gett a syntax error, you should always check if you got the syntax right in the mysql manual first. Had you checked mysql manual on alter table (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), you would have seen that it does not support if not exists for add column. Furthermore, please do not treat mysql and mariadb as the same product. These two forked about 15 years ago.
